# Turn on led backlight without a laptop

Tags: laptop

I'd like to turn on a broken laptop LED backlight  without laptop and use it as light panel.
How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: Start with the data sheet for the backlight - do you have one? Can you find one?

Comment: Hi, welcome! Can you find any part number on which could lead us to identify what part it is? Can you provide photos, or measurements? In general, showing that you've already made some research before asking will help attract more people to help you on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Most laptop LED back-lights are based of 1 or multiple constant current boost drivers, you would likely need to identify which pins are the LED's (may be documented depending on the model), and then build a similar circuit to power them,

If you know the make and model, the technical information of what pin does what, and possibly even what voltage and current is used may be available.